# How to plot the survival curve from a cox analysis?

Tags: r

I was following a tutorial on how to do a cox analysis, but can't get the plot right. The first part of my code, until the multivariate analysis, works fine.

After that when I try to plot the ggcurve, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in "           ggtheme = theme_minimal())"
```

Code:

```
install.packages("survival")
install.packages("survminer")

library("survival")
library("survminer")

data("lung")
lung

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog, data =  lung)

summary(res.cox)

ggsurvplot(survfit(res.cox), data = lung,
           ggtheme = theme_minimal())
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your opening and closing parentheses correct? I ran your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: I ran the code again in a new script and there it works fine. In my old script it now says with the following code that there is an unexpected symbol in "ggsurvplot(res.cox)  data". The code I used is                                                  
 ggsurvplot(res.cox)  data = lung
           ggtheme = theme_minimal()

Comment: Close as a typo. (There were several missing commas in the comment code.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
library("survival")
library("survminer")
data("lung")
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit,
       pval = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE,
       risk.table = TRUE, # Add risk table
       risk.table.col = "strata", # Change risk table color by groups
       linetype = "strata", # Change line type by groups
       surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
       ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
       palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"))
```

[image]

Comment: @TalithaVincken If it is good for you, please accept the answer. Best regards